# Density plot for negative values with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot2 package quiet frequently for my graphs, including kernel density plot. So far I had not encountered weird error, but now I have:

**Error in as.environment(where) : 'where' is missing ***

I have data vector which is having negative values in it, ranging from -1000 to -100. For positive values same piece of code is working but not for negative values. Below is the vignette:

```
sign <- c(-1000, -800, -700, -100, -500, -250, -100, -850, -100, -700)
p <- ggplot(plot_data, aes(x=sign, fill=Status)) + geom_density(alpha = 0.5) + xlab ("Signature")+ ylab("Density")
```

Here is a `dput` of the `plot_data` data frame.

```
structure(list(Sample = c(107453L, 107458L, 107457L, 107462L, 
107454L, 107459L, 107455L, 107460L, 107456L, 107461L), Status = c("Control", 
"Control", "CyP Treated (1 Hr)", "CyP Treated (1 Hr)", "CyP Treated (3 Hrs)", 
"CyP Treated (3 Hrs)", "LPS Treated (3 Hrs)", "LPS Treated (3 Hrs)", 
"Cyp+LPS Treated (3 Hrs)", "Cyp+LPS Treated (3 Hrs)"), sign = c(-1000L, 
-800L, -700L, -100L, -500L, -250L, -100L, -850L, -100L, -750L
)), .Names = c("Sample", "Status", "sign"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Can anybody please help me out from this, since none of the value is NA?

Comment: Without knowing what's in your `plot_data` there's not much we can do. Make a little self-contained example that illustrates the problem with a small dataset you can include here.

Comment: I have edited table and added table (plot_data data frame) in above question.

Comment: Show us how it works with positive data, because I can't see where you've set the "y" aesthetic which `geom_density` needs. If I change `sign` to its positive value I get the same error.

Comment: @Spacedman: This is not positive or negative values related issue, I guess, since for else other datasets I am getting proper result with above vignette but not with this particular dataset. Neither should this related to "y" aesthetic, since I am getting expected result with same piece of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your data frame and this code (a broken out version of your example):

```
p <- ggplot(plot_data, aes(x=sign, fill=Status))
p <- p + geom_density(alpha=0.5)
p <- p + xlab ("Signature") + ylab("Density")
p <- p + theme_bw()
p
```

The error I get (which is different than yours) is:

```
Error in exists(name, env) : argument "env" is missing, with no default
```

If I re-create your data frame but add one extra sample per `Status`:

```
set.seed(1492)
nsamp=3
dat <- data.frame(Status = rep(c("Control", "CyP Treated (1 Hr)", 
                                 "CyP Treated (3 Hrs)", "LPS Treated (3 Hrs)", 
                                 "Cyp+LPS Treated (3 Hrs)"), each=nsamp), 
                 sign = sample(seq(-1000, -100, by=50), 5*nsamp, replace=TRUE))
p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=sign, fill=Status))
p <- p + geom_density(alpha=0.5)
p <- p + xlab ("Signature") + ylab("Density")
p <- p + theme_bw()
p
```

I get this:

[image]

(the generated data frame with only 2 readings per `Status` fails the same way as the original).

Can you paste a `dput(plot_data)` in the event there are more readings per `Status`?

Comment: Thanks hrbrmstr, it is happening same way for me, not for two but happening for more than two readings in each status group. But unfortunately I don't have extra genuine readings.